# Rails annoying message We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

****We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.****

On various rails applications I have been getting this all the time. How can this be fixed for good on ruby on rails apps?

Comment: For good? Simple. Quit deploying applications with errors to production...

Comment: https://stillpoint-global-airbrake.airbrake.io/projects/112826

Comment: You really have to learn to read error messages and LOGS. LOGS are the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to check the log and fix the error, for production application you can use services like [airbreak](https://airbrake.io/) or [errbit](https://github.com/errbit/errbit) a free solution. Whenever this page occurs you will receive full trace and error. Hope this will help you in making application much more stable.

Comment: I understand but the issue is my entire site broke. Is there a way to stop this completely because its very bad on a live site. Any solution for this?

Comment: I suggest you revert your production to the last known good version.... if you don't even have that then well... you might as well learn how to debug errors using logs or start from scratch. Asking to fix that general of an error is asking for trouble here.